# Automatic .net 6 EF migration fails in docker

Tags: .net, postgresql, docker, entity-framework

I have the following problem. I am using docker-compose(Linux containers in docker) file to containerize my small web API and postgres Database. My docker-compose file looks like this:

```
version: '3.9'


services:
    web:
        container_name: sourceryapi
        build: .
        ports:
            - "8000:80"
        depends_on:
            database:
                    condition: service_healthy
    database:
        container_name: postgres
        image: postgres:latest
        ports: 
            - "5433:5432"
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin
        volumes:
            - dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
            #- ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U postgres"]
            interval: 10s
            timeout: 25s
            retries: 5
volumes:
  dbdata:
```

My Program.cs file looks like this:

```
global using SourceryAPI.Data;
global using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;



// Add services to the container.
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);



// Add services to the container.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
//var connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DB_CONNECTION_STRING");
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<SourceryContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseNpgsql(connectionString);
});


// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

var app = builder.Build();

await using var scope = app.Services.CreateAsyncScope();
using var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<SourceryContext>();
await db.Database.MigrateAsync();

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();

//app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

when I am running docker-compose up the postgres container is getting build without problems, but I got errors with my api in Program.cs lines 31 and 42:

```
Image for service web was built because it did not already exist. To rebuild this image you must use `docker-compose build` or `docker-compose up --build`.
Creating postgres ... 

Creating postgres ... done

Creating sourceryapi ... 

Creating sourceryapi ... done

Attaching to postgres, sourceryapi
[36mpostgres    |[0m The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
[36mpostgres    |[0m This user must also own the server process.
[36mpostgres    |[0m 
[36mpostgres    |[0m The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
[36mpostgres    |[0m The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
[36mpostgres    |[0m The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
[36mpostgres    |[0m 
[36mpostgres    |[0m Data page checksums are disabled.
[36mpostgres    |[0m 
[36mpostgres    |[0m fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
[36mpostgres    |[0m creating subdirectories ... ok
[36mpostgres    |[0m selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
[36mpostgres    |[0m selecting default max_connections ... 100
[36mpostgres    |[0m selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
[36mpostgres    |[0m selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC
[36mpostgres    |[0m creating configuration files ... ok
[36mpostgres    |[0m running bootstrap script ... ok
[36mpostgres    |[0m performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
[36mpostgres    |[0m syncing data to disk ... ok
[36mpostgres    |[0m 
[36mpostgres    |[0m 
[36mpostgres    |[0m Success. You can now start the database server using:
[36mpostgres    |[0m 
[36mpostgres    |[0m     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
[36mpostgres    |[0m 
[36mpostgres    |[0m initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
[36mpostgres    |[0m You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
[36mpostgres    |[0m --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
[36mpostgres    |[0m waiting for server to start....2022-04-29 14:18:44.264 UTC [49] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.2 (Debian 14.2-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
[36mpostgres    |[0m 2022-04-29 14:18:44.266 UTC [49] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
[36mpostgres    |[0m 2022-04-29 14:18:44.272 UTC [50] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-04-29 14:18:44 UTC
[36mpostgres    |[0m 2022-04-29 14:18:44.275 UTC [49] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
[36mpostgres    |[0m  done
[36mpostgres    |[0m server started
[36mpostgres    |[0m 
[36mpostgres    |[0m /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
[36mpostgres    |[0m 
[36mpostgres    |[0m 2022-04-29 14:18:44.385 UTC [49] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
[36mpostgres    |[0m waiting for server to shut down....2022-04-29 14:18:44.392 UTC [49] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
[36mpostgres    |[0m 2022-04-29 14:18:44.394 UTC [49] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 56) exited with exit code 1
[36mpostgres    |[0m 2022-04-29 14:18:44.395 UTC [51] LOG:  shutting down
[36mpostgres    |[0m 2022-04-29 14:18:44.407 UTC [49] LOG:  database system is shut down
[36mpostgres    |[0m  done
[36mpostgres    |[0m server stopped
[36mpostgres    |[0m 
[36mpostgres    |[0m PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
[36mpostgres    |[0m 
[36mpostgres    |[0m 2022-04-29 14:18:44.516 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.2 (Debian 14.2-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
[36mpostgres    |[0m 2022-04-29 14:18:44.516 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
[36mpostgres    |[0m 2022-04-29 14:18:44.516 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
[36mpostgres    |[0m 2022-04-29 14:18:44.520 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
[36mpostgres    |[0m 2022-04-29 14:18:44.525 UTC [61] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-04-29 14:18:44 UTC
[36mpostgres    |[0m 2022-04-29 14:18:44.528 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
[33msourceryapi |[0m {"EventId":10403,"LogLevel":"Information","Category":"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure","Message":"Entity Framework Core 6.0.4 initialized \u0027SourceryContext\u0027 using provider \u0027Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL:6.0.3\u002B94d0a8eaeb9cf5af6ce55a9e59153c1a1be3244f\u0027 with options: None","State":{"Message":"Entity Framework Core 6.0.4 initialized \u0027SourceryContext\u0027 using provider \u0027Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL:6.0.3\u002B94d0a8eaeb9cf5af6ce55a9e59153c1a1be3244f\u0027 with options: None","version":"6.0.4","contextType":"SourceryContext","provider":"Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL","providerVersion":"6.0.3\u002B94d0a8eaeb9cf5af6ce55a9e59153c1a1be3244f","options":"None","{OriginalFormat}":"Entity Framework Core {version} initialized \u0027{contextType}\u0027 using provider \u0027{provider}:{providerVersion}\u0027 with options: {options}"}}
[33msourceryapi |[0m Unhandled exception. Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): Failed to connect to [::1]:5432
[33msourceryapi |[0m  ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (99): Cannot assign requested address
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.CreateException(SocketError error, Boolean forAsyncThrow)
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ConnectAsync(Socket socket)
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.ConnectAsync(EndPoint remoteEP, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.<>c__DisplayClass198_0.<ConnectAsync>b__4(CancellationToken ct)
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at Npgsql.TaskExtensions.ExecuteWithTimeout(Func`2 func, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at Npgsql.TaskExtensions.ExecuteWithTimeout(Func`2 func, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.ConnectAsync(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.ExecutionContextCallback(Object s)
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext(Thread threadPoolThread)
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext()
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(IAsyncStateMachineBox box, Boolean allowInlining)
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(Object continuationObject)
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageThree()
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageTwo()
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishSlow(Boolean userDelegateExecute)
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.TrySetException(Object exceptionObject)
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.SetException(Exception exception, Task`1& taskField)
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.SetException(Exception exception)
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at Npgsql.TaskExtensions.ExecuteWithTimeout(Func`2 func, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.ExecutionContextCallback(Object s)
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext(Thread threadPoolThread)
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext()
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(IAsyncStateMachineBox box, Boolean allowInlining)
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(Object continuationObject)
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageThree()
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageTwo()
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishSlow(Boolean userDelegateExecute)
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.TrySetException(Object exceptionObject)
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.SetException(Exception exception, Task`1& taskField)
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder.SetException(Exception exception)
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.<ConnectAsync>g__WaitForConnectWithCancellation|277_0(AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs saea, ValueTask connectTask, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.ExecutionContextCallback(Object s)
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext(Thread threadPoolThread)
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext()
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at System.Threading.ThreadPool.<>c.<.cctor>b__86_0(Object state)
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.InvokeContinuation(Action`1 continuation, Object state, Boolean forceAsync, Boolean requiresExecutionContextFlow)
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.OnCompleted(SocketAsyncEventArgs _)
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.OnCompletedInternal()
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.CompletionCallback(Int32 bytesTransferred, SocketFlags flags, SocketError socketError)
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.ConnectCompletionCallback(SocketError socketError)
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncContext.ConnectOperation.InvokeCallback(Boolean allowPooling)
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncContext.OperationQueue`1.ProcessAsyncOperation(TOperation op)
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncContext.WriteOperation.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.Execute()
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncContext.HandleEvents(SocketEvents events)
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEngine.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.Execute()
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at System.Threading.PortableThreadPool.WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart()
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at System.Threading.Thread.StartCallback()
[33msourceryapi |[0m --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at Npgsql.TaskExtensions.ExecuteWithTimeout(Func`2 func, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.ConnectAsync(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.ConnectAsync(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.RawOpen(SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean isFirstAttempt)
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.<Open>g__OpenCore|191_1(NpgsqlConnector conn, SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean isFirstAttempt)
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at Npgsql.UnpooledConnectorSource.Get(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<Open>g__OpenAsync|45_0(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.ExistsAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.MigrateAsync(String targetMigration, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in /source/Program.cs:line 31
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in /source/Program.cs:line 42
[33msourceryapi |[0m    at Program.<Main>(String[] args)
[33msourceryapi exited with code 139
```

So it looks like there is an issue with my automate migration on startup part:

```
29    await using var scope = app.Services.CreateAsyncScope();
30    using var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<SourceryContext>();
31    await db.Database.MigrateAsync();
    
    ...
    
42    app.Run();
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?
Thx

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and guess that you have `localhost` specified as the database host name in your connection string.

In a Docker context, each container has its own IP address, so using localhost doesn't work.

On the Docker network set up by compose, you can address the containers by their service names or their container_name if that's been set. So in your case, you should use `postgres` instead of `localhost` in your connection string.